Как настроить расход только по определенному документу в регистре накопления в 1С?
Я занимаюсь настройкой движения приходов и расходов в регистре накопления "Резервирование" (измерения = Товар, ресурс = Количество) и нуждаюсь в помощи с обработкой расходных операций. Документ "ЗаказПокупателя" фиксирует приход, а документ "РасходнаяНакладная" — расход. У документа "РасходнаяНакладная" есть реквизит "Заказы", который ссылается на документ "ЗаказПокупателя". Как организовать расход только по конкретному документу "ЗаказПокупателя"? Например, если было проведено четыре прихода, как сделать так, чтобы расход осуществлялся только по второму документу "ЗаказПокупателя"? Я новичок в 1С и сталкиваюсь с этой проблемой впервые.
Вот Код для Прихода:
// регистр Резервирование Приход
Движения.Резервирование.Записывать = Истина;
Для Каждого ТекСтрокаПереченьНоменклатуры Из ПереченьНоменклатуры Цикл
    Движение1 = Движения.Резервирование.Добавить();
    Движение1.ВидДвижения = ВидДвиженияНакопления.Приход;
    Движение1.Период = Дата;
    Движение1.Документ = Документы.ЗаказПокупателя;
    Движение1.Товар = ТекСтрокаПереченьНоменклатуры.Товар;
    Движение1.Количество1 = ТекСтрокаПереченьНоменклатуры.Количество;
КонецЦикла;


Не понятно, что подразумевается под "расход по определенному документу". Если речь про резервирование, то у вас одно измерение - товар. Поэтому резерв анализируется по товару.
Сформулируйте полностью задачу.

расход по документу, я провожу приход по документу "ЗаказПокупателя", допустим провел 4 раза документ "ЗаказПокупателя" у меня появились 4 разных документа "ЗаказПокупателя" и 4 движения приход в регистре накопления "Резервирование", я же хочу по документу "РасходнаяНакладная" сделать расход допустим только по второму документу из четырех. сам документ я выбираю в реквbзите "Заказы" и именно оттуда код модуля объекта должен получать документ и по нему проводить расход, я могу 2 раза сделать приход на один товар но в разном количестве, значит создать 2 документа на один товар

Значит у вас структура регистра не правильная, если вам нужно резервирование вести в разрезе заказов.

У вас РегистрНакопления.Резервирования подразумевает, что вы приходом сваливаете Товар в кучу, а расходом забираете из кучи (без учета документов); Если необходимо забирать товар по Документам (как вы описали в задаче), Регистр должен содержать Измерение - "Документ" в который Приход должен записывать свою Ссылка, а Расход записывать Ссылка из реквизита документа

я добавил в регистр накопления Резервирования Измерение:Документ с типом ссылка на Документ.ЗаказПокупателя, код выглядит так "движение.Документ = Документы.ЗаказПокупателя;", а в расход я не знаю как обратиться к реквизиту документа "Заказы", я успешно провел документ "ЗаказПокупателя" через функции технического специалиста посмотрел движения Резервирования, в колонке Документ пусто

я заметил, что у движении регистра Резервирования есть регистратор куда внесен документ по которому было проведение, может в реквизит "Заказы" указать его

Движение1.Документ = Ссылка;  // Нужно записывать ссылку на текущий док который делает движение, а при расходе = Заказы
